# PhpStorm: Save as Live Template does nothing

Tags: phpstorm

Trying to create a Live Template in PhpStorm by highlighting a block of text, going to `Tools > Save as Live Template`.

When I do this, nothing happens. The Live Template dialog does not open and there is no other indication of an error. I can manually open the Live Template menu and add one there.

Is there a setting or configuration that is needed for this to be enabled?

PhpStorm 2017.1.4 on Windows 10

Comment: I see the same behaviour -- please report to their Issue Tracker at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: For reference, here's the issue I opened.  I'll update if there's a resolution. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-36840

Answer (score 0):

You can turn a highlighted block into a live template, but you need to make sure that there is no leading whitespace in your selected text, or it won't do anything, as explained in the original question.

This is likely a bug, see the issue in the comments to track resolution.